# Can I build Android Studio project without having to install Android Studio and Android SDK?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Say I have copied my source code of Android Studio project to a machine where neither Android Studio is installed nor Android SDK. I just have Gradle installed and I want to build project via command prompt. I'm familiar that SDK is mentioned as requirement on official Android website, but is there any work around? I just want to make build, nothing more.

Comment: Simply put: no. It is *required* as Junius told you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the Android SDK installed as this is a dependency of your project. You do not need Android Studio however.

You can use the gradle wrapper associated with the project (if you have one, otherwise install gradle) to build, compile and run your project. This is how continuous integration servers do automatic unit testing.

See http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html#building_gradle

Comment: Very well. BTW, it is an attempt for continuous integration.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm familiar that SDK is mentioned as requirement on official Android website, but is there any work around?

No. Copy the stuff back to the original machine, or install the Android SDK on the machine you are trying to build on.

> I just want to make build, nothing more.

That requires the tools and libraries that comprise the Android SDK. The complete and entire point behind the Android SDK is to allow you to "make build, nothing more" of an Android app.